# C#. Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

[image: Вот такая ошибка выскакивает]

```
 private Boolean getQw()
    {
        xmlReader.Read(); //error
        if (xmlReader.Name == "q")
        {
            qw = xmlReader.GetAttribute("text");
            xmlReader.Read();
            int i = 0;
            while (xmlReader.Name != "q")
            {
                xmlReader.Read();
                if (xmlReader.Name == "a")
                {
                    if (xmlReader.GetAttribute("right") == "yes")
                        right = i;
                    xmlReader.Read();
                    if (i < 3) answ[i] = xmlReader.Value;
                    xmlReader.Read();
                    i++;
                }
            }
            xmlReader.Read();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

...

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (mode)
        {
            case 0:
                radioButton1.Visible = true;
                radioButton2.Visible = true;
                radioButton3.Visible = true;

                this.getQw();//error
                this.showQw();

                mode = 1;

                button1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton4.Checked = true;
                break;

            case 1:
                nv++;

                if (otv == right) n++;

                if (this.getQw()) this.showQw();
                else
                {
                    radioButton1.Visible = false;
                    radioButton2.Visible = false;
                    radioButton3.Visible = false;

                    pictureBox1.Visible = false;

                    this.showLevel();

                    mode = 2;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                this.Close();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: дак и где у вас создается `xmlReader` ?

Comment: Очень не читаемый код. Попробуйте использовать XmlDocument с его функционалом XPath, будет куда более проще для ваших целей.

Comment: Перед строкой: 
'private Boolean getQw()'
Создается таким образом:
'System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader;'

Comment: Код не читаемый, потому что я noob (новичок).

Comment: 'System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader;' Как он таким образом создаётся?

Comment: Я включил  'XmlReader' из пространства имен 'System.Xml;'

Comment: Я понял проблему. Есть две формы. Первая форма - запускающаяся, Из первой при нажатии переходит на вторую. Если в Program.cs указать в качестве запускающейся вторую форму и задав в конструкторе так: 
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
               Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1(args));
            }`
То вторая форма запускается.

Comment: А если так: 

' static void Main()

        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();

            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form());
        }'
То нет.
P.S.: я не разобрался на сайте, как в нормальном виде оформлять код и отправить. Извиняйте